# it is possible to sign with a local digital certificate with docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the docusign api to generate envelopes dynamically. Is it possible to indicate when generating an envelope that the signers must use a digital certificate that they have installed on their computers to validate their signature?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use certificates if they're from [valid TSPs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/tsp-api/). TSPS provide an interface for sending and signing documents online and work with the appropriate Certificate Authorities to provide [trusted digital certificates](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/electronic-signature/digital-signature/digital-signature-faq).

[Read more about Standard Based Signatures](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Standards_Based_Signatures.pdf)